# Sistema de votaciones con php y cookies

Tags: php, html

estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio para clase, los enunciados son los siguientes:

El sistema de votos tan solo permite votar una vez, a la próxima que se intente votar debe mostrarse un mensaje que diga, ya has votado (y el equipo al que has votado). De este ejercicio sólo me falta saber cómo puedo hacer para que salga en el segundo mensaje el nombre del equipo votado anteriormente

En el segundo ejercicio, lo mismo, pero esta vez podremos votar 2 veces, evidentemente se tendrán que mostrar los nombres votados.

El tercero podremos votar tres veces, pero dejando un margen de 10 segundos.

La verdad estoy bastante perdido en estos dos últimos ejercicios, a ver si alguien puede ayudarme, este es el código que tengo hecho hasta ahora:

Fichero dades.php:

```
<?php
  //variable global amb tots els equips que
  //es poden votar.
  $equips = array(
      0 => 'Barça',
      1 => 'Real Madrid',
      2 => 'Girona',
      3 => 'Espanyol'
  );
?>
```

Fichero principal index.php:

```
<html>
    <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $cookie_name = "votar";
        $cookie_value = "1";
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (30 * 24 * 3600));
    }
    ?>
    <header></header>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <H1>FIFA WORLD PLAYERS 2018</H1>  
    <form method="post">
        <?php
            include_once "dades.php";

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
            foreach ($equips as $equip) {
                echo "<input type='radio' name='equip' value='$equip'/>$equip<br/>";
            }
            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>";
            echo '</form>';
        }else {
            $equip = $_POST["equip"];

            if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
                echo 'Has votat a ' . $_POST["equip"];
            } else {
                echo '<br>No pots votar més';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lee el [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?
](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Si controlas al usuario por medio de cookies, con borrar las cookies o entrar en modo privado, podrán votar cuanto quieran. Si aún así, prefieres las cookies, una forma de saber quién votó qué, sería añadir un campo más en la cookie con dicha información, pero no lo recomeindo.

Comment: Sé que no es fiable por eso que comentas, pero es simplemente un ejercicio para clase para que veamos el funcionamiento, pero desconozco cómo guardar qué votó x usuario en el cookie...

Comment: En tu código lo usas: setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)); entonces: setcookie("equip_votat", $equip, time() + (30 * 24 * 3600));